# Xterm does not display one uni-code character

Tags: terminal, xfce, unicode, xterm, xfce4-terminal

My `xterm` supports uni-code. For instance, it displays the Euro sign:

```
echo -e '\xe2\x82\xac'
```

But it does not display one particular character:

```
PL_BRANCH=$'\ue0a0'
echo $PL_BRANCH
```

This character displays properly in another terminal (terminator). I am using same font in both terminals (Inconsolata).

What could be the reason and how can I fix it ?

Comment: I don't think you'll get a more *reputable source* here than from @ThomasDickey as he is the maintainer of `xterm`.

Comment: Related:[Why are these fancy characters not shown in my prompt?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/320735)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modern terminal application uses additional fonts other than the default one when a character is unknown **but** xterm uses exclusively a single font (except for the special cases of double-width characters)

The needed char `$'\ue0a0'`, `echo $'\ue0a0'` is part of OpenSymbol font, we can use it with `xterm` but as that font does not include normal characters this would make it unusable, thus one solution is to use a patched font that include the needed special char and load it with the following

```
xterm -fa 'Inconsolata for Powerline'
```

We can as well set the size of the font as follow

```
xterm -fa 'Inconsolata for Powerline' -fs 16
```

This settings can be applied to the current user by adding the following to `~/.Xresources` or system widely on `/etc/X11/app-defaults/XTerm`

```
XTerm*faceName: Inconsolata for Powerline
```

Links: [1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96962/how-can-i-find-the-default-font-resource-xterm-is-using), [2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37260/change-font-in-echo-command), [3](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/280843/xterm-doesnt-display-some-unicode-characters-properly), [4](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161652/how-to-change-the-default-font-size-of-xterm), [5](https://github.com/powerline/fontpatcher) and [6](https://github.com/powerline/fonts/tree/master/Inconsolata)

Comment: that works, thank you

Answer (score 6):

The character is actually not in the font you indicated.  You can see this using `xfd`:

```
xfd -fa inconsolata
```

That shows the last codepoint is U+2423.  Reading a little further, it turns out that the character is in the Unicode [*private use*](https://codepoints.net/U+E0A0?lang=en) area, and (notwithstanding the fact that *some* font may provide it) has no standard meaning.

Since [late 2018](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_338), xterm can load multiple TrueType fonts, but none of the fonts at hand have U+E0A0.

If you can identify the actual font which is used, someone can point out which versions of xterm can deal with it.

Addressing a comment about `terminator` (which I don't happen to have installed), `terminator` doesn't use the same library interfaces as xterm, which affect the font-searching (none of either is well documented). You could use `strace` to see which font-files it actually opens.

For example, exploring this a little with `strace`, `konsole` and `pterm` on my Debian/testing both open one of the OpenOffice fonts for this character:

```
2600  openat(AT_FDCWD, "/users/tom/foo", O_RDONLY               
2600  )             = 3                                     
2586  openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/fonts/truetype/openoffice/opens___.ttf", O_R>
2601  openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC   
2601  )             = 4
```

(That's the "OpenSymbol" family's file).

On the other hand, I see that `rxvt-unicode` does not display the character, in spite of having several [font-patterns](https://github.com/exg/rxvt-unicode/blob/master/src/rxvtfont.C#L138) added to its search-list to (try to) work around problems such as this (which ultimately reflects a problem in fontconfig).  Very likely you'd find something similar (but ***different***) in the libraries which support konsole and pterm.

Comment: thank you. But the weird thing is, I am using the same font in `terminator`, and there it works.

Comment: So assuming the OP has access to a truetype font like https://raw.githubusercontent.com/powerline/powerline/develop/font/PowerlineSymbols.otf that has a glyphs for U+E0A0, how would they invoke/configure xterm so it renders characters using a generic font like `DejaVu Sans Mono`, but falls back to that `PowelineSymbols` font (assuming it's installed system-wide) for U+E0A0 (and other characters not covered by DejaVu but covered by that font)? Where can we find a specification for the format of the argument to `-fa`/`faceName`?

Comment: xterm's [manpage](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#VT100-Widget-Resources:faceName), and (of course) the fontconfig documentation, e.,g [FcFontSort](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/fontconfig/fontconfig-devel/fcfontsort.html), which needs a tutorial...